# Remove a namespace from an RDF resource

Tags: java, regex, uri

I am working on a Java project where I generate URIs (Uniform Resource Identifiers) as outputs.
An example of a URI is: www.myexample.com/rgd/543/mary.

I need to extract the final part of such URIs which is mary in the previous URI.

I need a scalable solution since I may have URIs of different forms but I always need to get the last part after the "/".

For example I could have:
http://software.org/trg/poo/945/steve
or 
http://www.amazon.com/rggf/0956/dfgh/rgf/kk/adam

and I need to extract steve and adam from the previous URIs respectively.

I know that regex may work but do not have much experience in regex. 
Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of regex you can use `substring` and `lastIndexOf` methods on Strings representing your URIs, like

```
String[] data = { "http://software.org/trg/poo/945/steve",
        " http://www.amazon.com/rggf/0956/dfgh/rgf/kk/adam" };
for (String s:data)
    System.out.println(s.substring(s.lastIndexOf('/')+1));

//"http://software.org/trg/poo/945/steve
//                                ^
//                                lastIndexOf(`/`);
//                                
// but we don't want to return "/steve" but "steve" 
// so lets subtract string from index of last `/`
// increased by one
```

Output:

```
steve
adam
```